# In PHPExel can not change the active sheet

Tags: excel, phpexcel

Using PHPExel load already created a file and  am successfully  submitting data on the first sheet

```
require ('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require ('PHPExcel.php');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("../ndocs/month.xls");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValue('D16', '84');
```

and it is now necessary to make the data on the second sheet

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->setCellValue('E18', '115');
```

but it does not work

Comment: If you gave the correct answer, mark it

Answer (score 0):

You need before set active sheet

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheet(0)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D16', '84');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A12', 84);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.